# Lost session reloading the webpage, php $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, session-variables, reload

I did a simple php webpage that control a login connected to a mysql databse, it works good but if I reload the webpage I loose the `$_SESSION`, my code is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('clases/Usuario.php');

    // Declaración de variables
    $user = new Usuario();
    $msg = "";

    // Controlo el log in
    if (isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        try
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);
            $_SESSION['log'] = true;
            $msg = "Conectado";
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $msg = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Controlo el log off
    if (isset($_POST['logoff']))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = null;
        $_SESSION['log'] = null;
        $msg = "Desconectado";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    if ($msg != "") echo "<font color='red'><h2>" . $msg . "</h2></font>"; // Mensaje de error si se diera el caso
    // Controlo si está logueado o no
    if (isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'])
    {
?>
        <h1>Panel</h1>
        <form action='index.php' method='post'><input type='submit' name='logoff' id='logoff' value='Log off' /></form>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action='index.php' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Usuario:</b></td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='user' name='user' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Contraseña:</b></td>
                    <td><input type='password' id='pass' name='pass' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' id='login' name='login' value='Log in' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
<?php   
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I did many logins working very good, but I do not program `php` for long long time and probabbly I am missing something.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use session_start at the beginning of each page ?

Comment: you never call session_start(), so PHP is under no obligation to save your session data for you.

Comment: sorry, it was not showing the proper code, I have the 'session_start()' written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed, the problem was I was trying to store in `$_SESSION['user']` a `PDO Statement`, I did not know that it caused some problems such as mine, so **I fetched the PDOStatement before return** in `login` and now it is all fixed.